# Functions in structure

Tags: c, function, struct

Can structures contain functions?

Comment: They can, but there is no inherent advantage in usual C programming.

In C, all functions are in the global space anyway, so you get no information hiding by tucking them in a function. paxdiablo 's example is a way to organize functions into a struct, but you must see has to dereference each one anyway to use it.

The standard organizational structure of C is the File, with
the interfaces in the header and the implementations in the source.

That is how libc is done and that is how almost all C libraries are done.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

No, but they can contain function *pointers.*

If your intent is to do some form of polymorphism in C then yes, it can be done:

```
typedef struct {
    int (*open)(void *self, char *fspec);
    int (*close)(void *self);
    int (*read)(void *self, void *buff, size_t max_sz, size_t *p_act_sz);
    int (*write)(void *self, void *buff, size_t max_sz, size_t *p_act_sz);
    // And data goes here.
} tCommClass;
```

The `typedef` above was for a structure I created for a general purpose communications library. In order to initialise the variable, you would:

```
tCommClass *makeCommTcp (void) {
    tCommClass *comm = malloc (sizeof (tCommClass));
    if (comm != NULL) {
        comm->open  = &tcpOpen;
        comm->close = &tcpOpen;
        comm->read  = &tcpOpen;
        comm->write = &tcpWrite;
    }
    return comm;
}

tCommClass *makeCommSna (void) {
    tCommClass *comm = malloc (sizeof (tCommClass));
    if (comm != NULL) {
        comm->open  = &snaOpen;
        comm->close = &snaOpen;
        comm->read  = &snaOpen;
        comm->write = &snaWrite;
    }
    return comm;
}

tCommClass *commTcp = makeCommTcp();
tCommClass *commSna = makeCommSna();
```

Then, to call the functions, something like:

```
// Pass commTcp as first params so we have a self/this variable
//   for accessing other functions and data area of object.
int stat = (commTcp->open)(commTcp, "bigiron.box.com:5000");
```

In this way, a single type could be used for TCP, SNA, RS232 or even carrier pidgeons, with exactly the same interface.

Comment: So is this also one of the difference b/w struct and classes? Because as of i know only difference is struct have default public and class is default private

Comment: @Josh, I think you're actually right about the public/private being the only difference between struct/union in C++. This question was about C. I suspect functions _are_ allowed in C++ since `struct xyz { int fn(void); } a;` worked just fine in g++.

Comment: The parantheses around `commTcp.open` are unnecessary.

Comment: you can actually see examples of functions in structures in Linux kernel code. Check out linux kernel : Documentation/vfs.txt

Answer (score 5):

**edit Cleared up ambiguity with the use of 'data types'**

Not in C. `struct` types can only contain data.

From Section 6.7.2.1 of the ISO C99 Standard.

> **A structure or union shall not contain a member with incomplete or function type** (hence,
>   a structure shall not contain an instance of itself, but may contain a pointer to an instance
>   of itself), except that the last member of a structure with more than one named member
>   may have incomplete array type; such a structure (and any union containing, possibly
>   recursively, a member that is such a structure) shall not be a member of a structure or an
>   element of an array.

Comment: "contain data types" is a dangerously ambiguous (at least to a C++ user, where they can declare types) - "contain data" seems more accurate.  All made clear in the Standard though... :-).

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. A structure cannot contain a declaration of a function but they can contain a definition of a function. A structure can only contain data types, pointers, pointers to different function. You can make a pointer to a function and then access from the structure.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

struct full_name
{
  char *fname;
  char *lname;
  void (*show)(char *,char*);
};

void show(char *a1,char * a2)
{
  cout<<a1<<"-"<<a2<<endl;
}

int main()
{  
  struct full_name loki;
  loki.fname="Mohit";
  loki.lname="Dabas";
  loki.show=show;
  loki.show(loki.fname,loki.lname);

  return 0;     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C, structures are allowed to contain on data values and not the function pointers. Not allowed in C. but the following works literally fine when checked with gcc.

```
enter code here

#include <stdio.h>

struct st_func_ptr{
        int data;
        int (*callback) ();
};

int cb(){
        printf(" Inside the call back \n");
        return 0;
}

int main() {
        struct st_func_ptr sfp = {10, cb};

        printf("return value = %d \n",sfp.callback());

        printf(" Inside main\n");
        return 0;
}
```

So, am confused ...

Comment: Who says you can't have function pointers in a struct in `C`?

Comment: Yes, it seems you are mixing things up. Function pointers are allowed, functions themselves not.

Comment: callback  is a  pointer-to-function with 0 parameters returning int.

C will allow you to assign to callback by reference  any function matching
that function signature.

The use of the initialization list is what is new and special here.

The printf statement is valid C, but not good style. It is confusing as to 
intentions and if you saw it way down far away from the struct definition you might be bewildered as to what it was and have to go hunting.

Answer (score 0):

It's all right.
In the linux kernel code,you will find many structures contain functions.
such as:

```
/*


* The type of device, "struct device" is embedded in. A class
 * or bus can contain devices of different types
 * like "partitions" and "disks", "mouse" and "event".
 * This identifies the device type and carries type-specific
 * information, equivalent to the kobj_type of a kobject.
 * If "name" is specified, the uevent will contain it in
 * the DEVTYPE variable.
 */
struct device_type {
        const char *name;
        struct attribute_group **groups;
        int (*uevent)(struct device *dev, struct kobj_uevent_env *env);
        void (*release)(struct device *dev);
        int (*suspend)(struct device * dev, pm_message_t state);
        int (*resume)(struct device * dev);
};
```

Comment: Well, they're pointers to functions - much the same, except it takes some effort to initialise them, there's a risk of trying to use them when they're NULL or otherwise invalid, and they can be changed at run time....

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible to declare a function and the function definition is not allowed and that should be the function pointer.

Its based on C99 tagged structure.

Lokesh V

Answer (score -1):

They can, but there is no inherent advantage in usual C programming.

In C, all functions are in the global space anyway, so you get no information hiding by tucking them in a function. paxdiablo 's example is a way to organize functions into a struct, but you must see has to dereference each one anyway to use it.

The standard organizational structure of C is the File, with
the interfaces in the header and the implementations in the source.

That is how libc is done and that is how almost all C libraries are done.

Moder C compilers allow you to define and implement functions in the same source file, and even implement static functions in header files. This unfortunately leads to some confusion as to what goes where, and you can get unusual solutions like cramming functions into structs, source-only programs with no headers, etc.
You lose the advantage of separating interface from implementation that way.